# A problem with CRTP, containers and pointers

Tags: c++, iterator, crtp

I have this `CRTP` *base class*:

```
template <class Child>
    class Container {
            friend Child;
            Container() {};
        public:
            decltype(auto) begin() { return static_cast<const Child&>(*this).abegin(); }
            decltype(auto) end() { return static_cast<Child&>(*this).aend(); }
            decltype(auto) begin() const { return static_cast<const Child&>(*this).abegin(); }
            decltype(auto) end() const { return static_cast<const Child&>(*this).aend(); }
};
```

And now, an array, trying to be the Child of that container:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
    class Array: public Container<Array<T, N>> {
        public:
            T array[N];
        public:
            using iterator = zero::iterator::input_iter<T>;
            using const_iterator = zero::iterator::input_iter<const T>;

            // Iterator stuff
            iterator abegin() { return iterator(&array[0]); }
            iterator aend() { return iterator(&array[N]); }
            constexpr const_iterator abegin() const { return const_iterator(&array[0]); }
            constexpr const_iterator aend() const { return const_iterator(&array[N]); }

            /**
             * @brief returns the number of elements stored in the underlying array
             */
            [[nodiscard]]
            inline consteval int size() const noexcept { return N; }

            template <typename... InitValues>
            Array(InitValues... init_values) 
                : array{ init_values... } {}

    // code goes on...
```

Here it's the usage:

```
import std;
import zero;
import collections;
import iterator;
import container;
import type_info;

using namespace zero;

int main() {
    constexpr collections::Array a = collections::Array<long, 5>{1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L};
    Container b = collections::Array<long, 5>{1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L};

    std::cout << "Iterating over the values of a constexpr zero::collection!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "decltype a: " << zero::types::type_name<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
    
    for (long value : a)
        std::cout << " - [constexpr] Value: " << value << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Iterating over the values of a zero::container!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "decltype a: " << zero::types::type_name<decltype(b)>() << std::endl;
    for (long value : b)
        std::cout << " - Value: " << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the results:

```
Iterating over the values of a constexpr zero::collection!
decltype a: const zero::collections::Array<long, 5>
 - [constexpr] Value: 1
 - [constexpr] Value: 2
 - [constexpr] Value: 3
 - [constexpr] Value: 4
 - [constexpr] Value: 5

Iterating over the values of a zero::container!
decltype a: zero::Container<zero::collections::Array<long, 5>>
 - Value: 8
 - Value: 0
 - Value: 1
 - Value: 2
 - Value: 3
```

Well, I just got UB!

I am missunderstading things, pretty sure, but I am not able to understand what I am writting and doing bad.

- I want to be able to use `Container` as a interface type in type definitions, functions parameters... typical places without dynamic polimorphism, just using `CRTP`.

Is someone able to spot my mistakes and help me to fix them?

EDIT: As asked here is the [live example on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mrd5xf616)

Comment: What is `underlying`? Can you please turn this into a [mre]?

Comment: That's a lot of code.  That code is disjoint.  That code is incomplete.  Maybe the bug is not in the code provided.  Maybe it is.  But I'd have to reconstruct the incomplete code to find out.  That's a lot of work, and I might do something different and make a new bug that obscures your bug (since "bugs hide bugs").  Or I may accidentally fix the bug in your code trying to cobble these code snippets together.

Comment: Well, I added you guys a minimal reproducible example in Godbolt

Comment: You are not really gaining anything by using CRTP here. Only opportunities to introduce typos, that you didn't put to waste. If you at least were defining several versions of `begin` (for example) in terms of one in the child maybe that would be a useful CRTP.

Comment: @alfC well, code is far from complete. I mean, I did not write it yet. Suppose `std::get`. I could write a collection of different containers (array, list, vector, deque...) with a get method, everyone with it's impl... I Don't know really. I Am justo trying to figure out if it could be feasible

Comment: I Am just playing with the language capabilities for fun. But I guess that a concept would do a very much better job as being that kind of abstract interface that I am looking for

Comment: Some detailed material on CRTP in context, https://youtu.be/ABkxMSbejZI?t=2214

Comment: There is a whole Boost library for this that defines base CRTP classes to build container interfaces a-la STL. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/stl_interfaces.html . In particular take a look at the tutorial for `sequence_container_interface` . https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_stlinterfaces/tutorial___sequence_container_interface_.html . As you can see you provide (non-const) begin and end and the interface generates the rest for you.

Comment: @alfC it took me a while figuring it out, but that's a nice approach to what I am looking for

Comment: Great! please post your solution with STLInterfaces if you find one.

Comment: @alfC question is already closed, but you can take a look if you like to the project (is public here https://github.com/zerodaycode/Zero). I am busy these days, but I hope make progress with the task this incomig weekend :)

Comment: You can still add answers to your question. The question is not technically closed, it is just answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate reason of the UB is *object slicing*. The type of `b` is `Container<Array<long, 5>>` — and it is a *complete* object. There is no `Array<long, 5>` around to be a base class subobject of. The temporary `collections::Array<long, 5>{1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L}` isn't one. So every cast inside member functions of this particular container is UB.

In order to fix it, you need `b` to be a *reference* to a `Container`. Let's try:

```
const Container& b = collections::Array<long, 5>{1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L};
```

Oops! This doesn't compile. The reason why you was able to write just `Container` is CTAD, and CTAD doesn't work for references or pointers or anything but the class template itself. `Container` is *not a type* and cannot be used as such. It is a template. So not having CTAD on your side, you need this:

```
const Container<collections::Array<long, 5>> & b = 
   collections::Array<long, 5>{1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L};
```

(`const` because it's a reference to a temporary)

Now this doesn't look as attractive as just `Container`, does it? And if you need to spell out `collections::Array<long, 5>`, you could just as well write

```
const collections::Array<long, 5> & b = 
   collections::Array<long, 5>{1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L};
```

which is shorter and contains just as much information about `b`.

Now why do you need `Container` again?

Comment: well, answer is quite perfect.
But, for example, couldn't be useful for functions or templated functions (like the ones in algorithm)? I mean, CRTP is a quite useful pattern. boost::iterator_facace makes use of it.
Just should I get rid of it? Or there certains cases where the pain is worth the effort?

Comment: CRTP has a very specific and narrow utility: abstract away code that looks the same (but doesn't quite mean the same thing) in every derived class. A good example is `clone`. Every `clone` method looks essentially the same. Static polymorphism (a base class calls methods defined in a derived class) falls there too. Your code has none of this.

Comment: then may I wonder that may be a good usage for a hierarchy of iterators but makes no sense for the approach on containers?

Comment: It really depends on what specific functionality you want to abstract away to the base class.